# DIY Social media buttons Vs. Ready built (e.g. AddThis)

Tags: facebook, marketing, social-media

Is there any benefit from rolling-your-own set of social media 'like' buttons rather than using a pre-packaged widget, such as that provided by AddThis? Are there any downsides from using out of the box services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of the box services

- may go out of business
- their servers may go down
- they may not be responsive when new social media sites appear and their widget doesn't include them
- they may not be responsive when existing social media sites change their APIs in a way which breaks the widget
- you have a lot more control over behaviour and appearance

Of course rolling-your-own may be a lot of work, particularly if you're the one changing your widget because someone changed their API.

Comment: Good points.. +1

Comment: These are all valid down sides, but what if non of this happens? Assuming everything is working correctly, is there any disadvantage?

Comment: Only the fact that you are limited when it comes to appearance as to how the services choose to display the widgets.